# Append additional values to queryset in Django generic views before handing to template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following view:

```
class AppointmentListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    queryset = Appointment.objects.prefetch_related('client','patients')
```

I need to be able to add an extra variable to each returned Appointment object based on the following:

```
status_choices={
    'STATUS_UPCOMING':'default',
    'STATUS_ARRIVED':'primary',
    'STATUS_IN_CONSULT': 'success',
    'STATUS_WAITING_TO_PAY':'info',
    'STATUS_PAYMENT_COMPLETE':'warning',
}
```

The values ('default', 'primary' etc) correspond to standard css classesin Bootcamp themes that I want to use according to the type of Appointment. For example, 'default' produces a gray button, 'warning' a red button etc.

I need to map each Appointment record to a certain css button based on the record's status ('upcoming' would display the 'default' class etc).

My initial idea was to loop over the query set and build a separate array/dictionary mapping the Appointment pk to a given css class such as
`1:'success', 2:'warning'`, and then pass that in as a context variable.

But I was wondering if I could just add the value to each Appointment object directly (perhaps saving the queryset as a list?) That would be a much cleaner solution but am not sure how that should be approached.

Any ideas much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should overload the get_queryset method of the ListView like so

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    queryset = super(AppointmentListView, self).get_queryset(**kwargs)
    # Add new elements here
    ...
    return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks. How would  I go about updating each object in the queryset? For example adding `css_class = 'warning'` to only objects which satisfy that requirement.

Comment: You are probably at the point of creating custom form types here and overloading the `render_options` method on the field type.  But in truth, that is a separate question and probably should not be asked in the comments section here

Comment: Sounds like the same question as the one i first asked: how to add values to each Appointment object before the queryset is returned to the template.

So there's no easy way to 'intercept' the queryset and modify it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I completely misread your question.  I thought you wanted to append 'default' and 'primary' as values to the queryset.  My apologies.  I really think you might want to look at a custom type or filter the values in javascript and append the css in the front end

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by overriding get_queryset() and giving the objects (i.e. each row in the db) an extra on-the-fly key/value:

```
class AppointmentListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    #friendly template context
    context_object_name = 'appointments'
    template_name = 'appointments/appointment_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Appointment.objects.prefetch_related('client','patients')
        for r in qs:
            if r.status == r.STATUS_UPCOMING: r.css_button_class = 'default'
            if r.status == r.STATUS_ARRIVED: r.css_button_class = 'warning'
            if r.status == r.STATUS_IN_CONSULT: r.css_button_class = 'success'
            if r.status == r.STATUS_WAITING_TO_PAY: r.css_button_class = 'danger'
            if r.status == r.STATUS_PAYMENT_COMPLETE: r.css_button_class = 'info'
        return list(qs)
```

A couple of things:

1. I converted the queryset `qs` to a **list** to 'freeze' it. This prevents the queryset from being re-evaluated (e.g. slice) which, in turn, would cause the on-the-fly model changes to be lost as fresh data is pulled from DB.
2. I needed to assign a value to `template_name` explicitly. When overriding get_queryset the template name is not derived automagically. As a comparison, the code below whose `queryset` attribute is set, generates the template name automatically:

   ```
   class AppointmentListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
       queryset = Appointment.objects.prefetch_related('client', 'patients')
       #template name FOO_list derived automatically

   #appointments/views.py
   ...
   #can use derived name (FOO_list)
   {% for appointment in appointment_list %}
   ...
   ```